# Trash value em um array do C

Tags: c, array, índices

Eu estou fazendo um programa cuja função é importar os valores de um arquivo .dat e colocá-los dentro de um vetor. Para isso, fiz o seguinte código:

```
void Import_vec(int tamanho,const char caminho[],float * vetor,int chave)
{

    FILE *arquivo = fopen(caminho,"r");

    for(int i = 0;i<tamanho;i++)
    {
        fscanf(arquivo, "%f\t", &vetor[i]);
        if(chave == 1)
        {
            printf("%f\n",vetor[i]); // Caso seja 1, os valores serão impressos no terminal
        }
    }
    fclose(arquivo);
}
```

Na saída aparecem todos os valores corretos, mas ao terminar de imprimir o último valor aparece um trash value (valor gigantesco que não está no arquivo).

Output:

```
    0.918033
    -0.981341
    0.241689
    2.344740
    -1.605030
    -1.395590
    -1.280210
    1.801470
    -0.216157
    -1.634040
    23.3161324.0574250.878794-6.604258-8.68799711.96468212.795636-5.3303821.332010-8.0112750.7523827.292252-11.467504-0.8759   
2310.2975292.430890-13.0802069.1249843.690364-16.438658
```

Antes de usar `fscanf()` eu usei `fgets()`, `strtok` e `strtod` para ler a linha, separar os valores com base em um token e converter a string para um float, mas ainda assim dava o mesmo problema. O que pode ser? O que ocasiona isso? Como posso evitar? Outro problema: o tamanho do vetor é 10, mas com o trash value o vetor acaba tendo 11 valores. Como? (Para alocar o vetor usei `malloc(10*sizeof(float))`).
Caso precisem de informações adicionais, O código completo é:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

float *Alloc_vec(int n){
    float *v = malloc(n*sizeof(float));
    if(v == NULL)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return v;
}


float **Alloc_array(int n, int m){
    float **matriz;
    matriz = malloc(n*sizeof(float *));
    if(matriz == NULL)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        matriz[i] = malloc(m*sizeof(float ));
        if(matriz[i] == NULL){
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    return matriz;
}


void Import_vec(int tamanho,const char caminho[],float * vetor,int chave)
{

    FILE *arquivo = fopen(caminho,"r");

    for(int i = 0;i<tamanho;i++)
    {
        fscanf(arquivo, "%f\t", &vetor[i]);
        if(vetor[i] >10)
        {
            vetor[i] = 0;
        }
        sleep(1);
        if(chave == 1)
        {
            printf("%f\n",vetor[i]);
        }
    }
    fclose(arquivo);
}


void Import_array(int n, int m ,const char caminho[],float ** matriz,int chave)
{
    FILE *arquivo = fopen(caminho,"r");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            fscanf(arquivo, "%f ", &matriz[i][j]);
            if(chave == 1)
            {
                printf("%f ",matriz[i][j]);
            }
        }

    }
    fclose(arquivo);

}

int main(){
    int Ni=20,Nj=30,Nk=10;
    float *u = Alloc_vec(Nk);
    float *v = Alloc_vec(Nj);
    float **A = Alloc_array(Ni,Nk);
    float **B = Alloc_array(Nk,Nj);
    char caminho_u[] = "u_vec.dat";
    char caminho_v[] = "v_vec.dat";
    char caminho_A[] = "A_array.dat";
    char caminho_B[] = "B_array.dat";
    Import_vec(Nk,caminho_u,u,1);
    Import_vec(Nj,caminho_v,v,0);
    Import_array(Ni,Nk,caminho_A,A,0);
    Import_array(Nk,Nj,caminho_B,B,0);

    //Definição de C
    float **C = Alloc_array(Ni,Nj);
    for(int i = 0;i<Ni;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<Nj;j++)
        {
            C[i][j] = 0;
            for(int k = 0;k<Nk;k++)
            {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    //Definição de s
    float *s = Alloc_vec(Nk);
    for(int i = 0;i<Ni;i++)
    {
        s[i] = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<Nk;j++)
        {
            s[i] += A[i][j]*u[j];
        }
    }


    //Definição de r
    float *r = Alloc_vec(Nj);
    for(int i = 0;i<Ni;i++)
    {
        r[i] = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<Nj;j++)
        {
            r[i] += C[i][j]*v[j];

        }
        float numero = r[i];
        printf("%f",numero);
    }
    float z=0;
    for(int i = 0;i<Ni;i++)
    {
        z+=r[i]*s[i];
    }
   // printf("%f",z);
    for(int i = 0;i<Ni;i++)
    {
        free(A[i]);
    }
    free(A);
    for(int i = 0;i<Nk;i++)
    {
        free(B[i]);
    }
    free(B);
    for(int i = 0;i<Ni;i++)
    {
        free(C[i]);
    }
    free(C);
    free(r);
    free(s);
    free(u);
    free(v);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite, Lamparejo

Dei uma olhadinha no seu codigo e nao ficou muito claro a formatação do conteudo do arquivo que voce esta lendo, o que neste caso, faz toda a diferença.

Para tentar te ajudar o que eu fiz: Criei um programa que grava e lê de um mesmo arquivo uma sequencia de 5 floats.

A gravação é "fixa" com os primeiros valores que você informou.

Já a leitura, alimenta dinamicamente um vetor de floats, ate seu comprimento maximo 5(poderia ser 10, 20, tanto faz).
Espero que seja de serventia para você. Vejo que seu problema pode estar na lógica de "contagem" das posicoes de seu array.
Caso necessite de mais ajuda, nao hesite em pedir!
Em tempo, envia tambem o arquivo e se vc precisa que eu faça tambem utilizando malloc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TAMANHO_VETOR 5

int escreve_arquivo_vetor(){
    FILE *arquivoVetor;
    char *caminhoArquivoVetor = "arquivo_vetor.dat";
    
    if ( (arquivoVetor = fopen(caminhoArquivoVetor, "w")) == NULL )
        return -1;
        
    fprintf(arquivoVetor,
    "%f\n%f\n%f\n%f\n%f\n",
        0.918033,
        -0.981341,
        0.241689,
        2.344740,
        -1.605030
    );
    fclose(arquivoVetor);
    return 0;
}

void le_arquivo_vetor(float *vetorFloat){
    FILE *arquivoVetor;
    char *caminhoArquivoVetor = "arquivo_vetor.dat";
    char fileLine[128];
    int i = 0;
    
    if ( (arquivoVetor = fopen(caminhoArquivoVetor, "r")) == NULL )
        return;
    
    while ( fgets(fileLine, sizeof(fileLine), arquivoVetor) ){
        vetorFloat[i++] = atof(fileLine);
        if ( i >= TAMANHO_VETOR ) break;
    }
}

void imprime_vetor(float *vetorFloat){
    int i = 0;
    
    while ( i < TAMANHO_VETOR )
        printf ("vetorFloat[%d]=%f\n", i, vetorFloat[i++]);
    
    return;
}

int main(){
    float vetorFloat[TAMANHO_VETOR];
    float matrizFloat[5][5];
    
    if ( escreve_arquivo_vetor() < 0 )
        printf("erro ao escrever arquivo");
        
    le_arquivo_vetor(vetorFloat);
    
    imprime_vetor(vetorFloat);
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Os arquivos seguem essa formatação:

Os de vetores:
(u_vec)
0.918033
-0.981341
0.241689
2.34474
-1.60503
-1.39559
-1.28021
1.80147
-0.216157
-1.63404

e o de matriz é muito grande, mas ele é feito da forma que se espera: linhas e colunas com seus respectivos elementos.